# What is the difference between these two sentences

Tags: grammar, speech

"Hello Jack you are back I thought you are on holiday"  or

" Hello Jack you are back I thought you were on holiday"

What should I use when im speaking with someone ?

Comment: Both are correct, although the second one would be the preferred version.

Comment: Both would be better with some punctuation.

Comment: @Stockfish chasly disagrees about both sentences being correct. So do I. So, apparently, do [most people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=I+thought+you+are%2CI+thought+you+were&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20you%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20you%20were%3B%2Cc0).